# ASP.NET MVC how do I map requests to old locations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've just started an upgrade project from webforms to asp.net mvc 2. There is a file called resources.aspx in the root of the site that I need to intercept from mvc. If I start a new project I get a 404 if I try to access resources.aspx but I have created a resources controller. How do I make the controller map to /resources.aspx?

Comment: You need to look into ASP.NET MVC's routing features. MVC's routing takes care of mapping the URL and query string to the appropriate area, controller, and action. However, it always allows you to ignore specific routes.

Comment: hard to say from this much details. Can you show us some pieces of the code calling and perhaps some from the resources.aspx too? (if someone wants to rewrite it for you)

Comment: Do you have examples of these routing features for mapping to http://site/resources.aspx

Comment: I get it. Add route to the global.asax.cs: routes.MapRoute("Test", "resources.aspx", new {controller = "Resources", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without creating a controller.  Add this right below the routes.IgnoreRoute in RegisterRoutes:

```
    routes.MapPageRoute("ResourcesOldRoute","resources","~/resources.aspx");
```

Then to use it, your URL would be something like http://localhost/resources.

If for some reason you want the Controller then you will have to to redirect to it in the Index ActionResult.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Redirect("/resources.aspx");
}
```